# checked rows of table to array th as array index in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to push the checked row of HTML table only to array using jQuery.I need to have array index as the table header and value as the shell value of the checked column shell of the respective head.

I have HTML table as:

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="checkTable">
          <thead>
            <th style="width:20px;"><input type="checkbox" name="headercheck" id="checkAll"></th>
            <th>Programming Languages</th>
            <th>Popularity</th>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" class="table-checkbox"></td>
              <td>Java</td>
              <td>62%</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" class="table-checkbox"></td>
              <td>Python</td>
              <td>46%</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" class="table-checkbox"></td>
              <td>JavaScript</td>
              <td>38%</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" class="table-checkbox"></td>
              <td>C++</td>
              <td>31%</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" class="table-checkbox"></td>
              <td>C#</td>
              <td>27%</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" class="table-checkbox"></td>
              <td>PHP</td>
              <td>14%</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" class="table-checkbox"></td>
              <td>Pearl</td>
              <td>14%</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <button id='pushToArray'>Push To Array</button>
```

Now I need to push the selected rows of the table with the index value as the table head of the respective column.

```
$('div#tableContainer').find('button#pushToArray').on('click', function(){
        var array = new Array();
        var headers = new Array();
        table.find('th').each(function(index, item) {
            if(index == 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                headers[index] = $(item).html();
            }
        });

            var valueList = [];
        table.find('tbody tr').each(function() {
            $(this).find('input.table-checkbox:checked').each(function(){
                var values = [];
                $(this).closest('td').siblings('td').each(function(index, item){
                    values[headers[index]] = $(item).html();
                });
                valueList.push(values);
            });
        });
        console.log(valueList);
    });
```

I build headers successfully but while indexing i am getting my array as

```
[…]​
0: []​​
"Programming Languages": "14%"​​
length: 0​​
undefined: "PHP"​​
__proto__: Array []​
length: 1​
__proto__: Array []
```

what can be the best way for getting things right in the way i wanted it to be.

```js
$('div#tableContainer').find('button#pushToArray').on('click', function() {
  var array = new Array();
  var headers = new Array();
  table.find('th').each(function(index, item) {
    if (index == 0) {
      return true;
    } else {
      headers[index] = $(item).html();
    }
  });

  var valueList = [];
  table.find('tbody tr').each(function() {
    $(this).find('input.table-checkbox:checked').each(function() {
      var values = [];
      $(this).closest('td').siblings('td').each(function(index, item) {
        values[headers[index]] = $(item).html();
      });
      valueList.push(values);
    });
  });
  console.log(valueList);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered" id="checkTable">
  <thead>
    <th style="width:20px;"><input type="checkbox" name="headercheck" id="checkAll"></th>
    <th>Programming Languages</th>
    <th>Popularity</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="table-checkbox"></td>
      <td>Java</td>
      <td>62%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="table-checkbox"></td>
      <td>Python</td>
      <td>46%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="table-checkbox"></td>
      <td>JavaScript</td>
      <td>38%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="table-checkbox"></td>
      <td>C++</td>
      <td>31%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="table-checkbox"></td>
      <td>C#</td>
      <td>27%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="table-checkbox"></td>
      <td>PHP</td>
      <td>14%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="table-checkbox"></td>
      <td>Pearl</td>
      <td>14%</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button id='pushToArray'>Push To Array</button>
```

Comment: where is this `'div#tableContainer'` ,`table` variable?? please post [mcve]

Comment: the button is inside the div with id tableContainer

Comment: What output do you expect to get? @Alesh

Comment: I just want an array with table header as index and its value must be each checked row values only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get the *Programming Languages* checked, you can use `:checked` selector to get all checked checkbox. The `map` to get the text text of the next `<td>`

```js
$('#pushToArray').click(function() {
 
//Get all headers that dont contain checkAll checkbox
var headers = $("#checkTable thead th").filter(function(){
    return !$(this).find('#checkAll').length;
}).map(function(){
    return $(this).text().trim();
}).get();


//Loop thru the checked checkboxes
var arr = $('#checkTable .table-checkbox:checked').map(function(){ 
    var obj = {};
   
    $(this).parent().siblings().each(function(i){
          obj[ headers[i] ] = $(this).text().trim();
    })
    
    return obj;
}).get();

console.log(arr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered" id="checkTable">
  <thead>
    <th style="width:20px;"><input type="checkbox" name="headercheck" id="checkAll"></th>
    <th>Programming Languages</th>
    <th>Popularity</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="table-checkbox"></td>
      <td>Java</td>
      <td>62%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="table-checkbox"></td>
      <td>Python</td>
      <td>46%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="table-checkbox"></td>
      <td>JavaScript</td>
      <td>38%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="table-checkbox"></td>
      <td>C++</td>
      <td>31%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="table-checkbox"></td>
      <td>C#</td>
      <td>27%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="table-checkbox"></td>
      <td>PHP</td>
      <td>14%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="table-checkbox"></td>
      <td>Pearl</td>
      <td>14%</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button id='pushToArray'>Push To Array</button>
```

Comment: but i need table head as index

Comment: […]​
0: […]​​
"Programming Languages": "Python"​​
"Popularity": "46%"

Comment: yeah but it cant be static with the columns

Comment: You mean, the column names are dynamic? Are the positions dynamic as well?

Comment: The way you did gives only two column value but what if i have more than 2 columns in my table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169139/discussion-between-alesh-and-eddie).

Answer (score 0):

I used loop to to push the headers in array and used another loop to get table body values ignoring the checkbox as follows:

```
$('div#tableContainer').find('button#pushToArray').on('click', function(){
    console.log("Cool");
    var array = [];
    var headers = [];
    $('#checkTable th').each(function(index, item) {
        if(index == 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                headers[index] = $(item).html();
            }
    });
    $('#checkTable tr').has('td input.table-checkbox:checked').each(function() {
        var arrayItem = {};
        $('td', $(this)).each(function(index, item) {
            if(index == 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                arrayItem[headers[index]] = $(item).html();
            }
        });
        array.push(arrayItem);
    });
    console.log(array);
});
```